# apache2 error log showing browsing history

Tags: apache-2.2, windows

Example error

```
[Wed Feb 06 13:37:50 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: C:/app/apache2/htdocs/js/250, referer: http://www.diecastplus.com/hw-mj3-c3.html
```

I installed apache on a local windows machine for someone to show them updates for a application I was working on. Someone else found errors like this in the error.log. I have the same setup on my pc and I can't see it.I have no js/250 file in the application but what I have found there that refers http://s7.addthis.com/js/250/addthis_widget.js.

Is there any reason that a browser would misdirect http requests like this. I'm assuming its security software but I want to make sure because they think its something with the server I setup.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the provided information I can think of 2 scenarios that would cause this:
Some element on whatever webpage that person visited has a wrong URL to localhost or 127.0.0.1..Perhaps as a leftover from when that page was developed locally on somebody's computer.

Alternatively, if they have some adblocking software or "hosts" file that intercepts and redirects requests from some servers to localhost. That is done because most people don't run http server on their local computer so browser will instantly give up trying to connect.